# How to test onClick() funct and useState hooks using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I am new to this jest+enzyme testing and I am stuck at how to cover the lines and functions such as onClick(), the useState variables and also useffect(). Can anyone with any experience in such scenerios please give me some direction on how to do that efficiently.

Below is the code:

```
export interface TMProps {
  onClick: (bool) => void;
  className?: string;
  style?: object;
}
export const TM: React.FC<TMProps> = (props) => {
  const {onClick} = props;
  const [isMenuOpen, toggleMenu] = useState(false);
const handleUserKeyPress = (event) => {
    const e = event;
    if (
      menuRef &&
      !(
        (e.target.id && e.target.id.includes("tmp")) ||
        (e.target.className &&
          (e.target.className.includes("tmp-op") ||
            e.target.className.includes("tmp-option-wrapper")))
      )
    ) {
      toggleMenu(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment className="tmp">
      <Button
        className={props.className}
        style={props.style}
        id={"lifestyle"}
        onClick={() => toggleMenu((state) => !state)}>
        Homes International
        <FontAwesomeIcon iconClassName="fa-caret-down" />{" "}
      </Button>
      <Popover
        style={{zIndex: 1200}}
        id={`template-popover`}
        isOpen={isMenuOpen}
        target={"template"}
        toggle={() => toggleMenu((state) => !state)}
        placement="bottom-start"
        className={"homes-international"}>
        <PopoverButton
          className={
            "template-option-wrapper homes-international"
          }
          textProps={{className: "template-option"}}
          onClick={() => {
            onClick(true);
            toggleMenu(false);
          }}>
          Generic Template{" "}
        </PopoverButton>
         />
}
```

Here is the test I have written but it isn't covering the onClick(), useEffect() and handleUserKeyPress() function.

```
describe("Modal Heading", () => {
    React.useState = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true)
    it("Modal Heading Header", () => {
        const props = {
            onClick: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true),
            className: "",
            style:{}
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<TM {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(Button)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
    it("Modal Heading Header", () => {
        const props = {
            onClick: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true),
            className: "",
            style:{}
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<TM {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(Popover)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
    it("Modal Heading Header", () => {
        const props = {
            onClick: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true),
            className: "",
            style:{}
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<TM {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(PopoverButton)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is enzyme's:

```
const btn = wrapper.find('lifestyle');

btn.simulate('click');
wrapper.update();
```

Not sure if it'd trigger the window listener, it's possible you'll have to mock it.

Comment: Okay will try this , And how to test this useEffect() function?

Comment: In functional components you test the effects, not the functions themselves. So, test if your `isMenuOpen` is correctly toggled (via rendered content) or search for enzyme's `addEventListener` testing.

Comment: Got your point, looking into it, one more advice I need from you , as you can see there is this `toggle={() => toggleMenu((state) => !state)}` prop being passed in <Popover> component, so for onclick, btn.simulate is working, but for this toggle prop, it is not working, do you know any fix for this?

Comment: idk what this `Popover` actually is. Find out by console logging `wrapper.debug()` and see how to access the actual html element